# How to set position of html element (for child absolute position) without changing its position in page

Tags: html, position, absolute

I want to set position setting of `<h1>` which is an ancestor of `<span>`.

I want to do that because `<span>` position is set to absolute, and and want to set the absolute position of span relatively to `<h1>`.

So what I did was to set position of `<h1>` either to `relative` or `absulte`. In a part it works because the absolute position of span is then set relatively to `<h1>`, but now `<h1>` doesn't behave the same!

What I did finally was to set `<h1>` position to relative, and as the content of `<h1>` is not taken into account anymore, I put a div with a fixed height just after `<h1></h1>` in order for the next html element not to be positioned at the upper left position of `<h1>` but below this `<h1>`.

Is there a simpler and better way to set position of html element without changing its position in page?

For clarity, here is what I did:

```
<html><head>
<title>Hello world</title>

<style>
.positioned{
  position: relative;
}
.shift-25{
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  transform: traslateX(-25%);
}
</style>

</head><body>
<h1 class="positioned">
    <span class="shift-25">
    Hello World
    </span>
</h1>
<div>   content after positioned h1. </div>
</body></html>
```

And here is the result on browser:
[image: image of html positioned element for child with absolute position]
What I would like is to have `content after positioned h1` text below `Hello World` without using bad trick.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Having to guess what your HTML/CSS looks like from a text description is just not a good use of anyone's time.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you want. The `content after positioned h1` should be below the h1? Is it not like that without any tricks?

Comment: helena: no as you see in the result in the browser 'content after positioned h1' is on the left of 'Hello World' do you understand?

Comment: I don't think I do, but I'll try. Using `position: absolute` on the `<span>` is causing the Hello World to be floating in the page and thus the `<div>` goes up, right? I'd suggest getting rid of the positioning altogether and applying a better spacing to the `h1` such as `padding`, `margin` or `text-align`.

Comment: The problem is that if I do that, I guess it wouldn't work because the H1 position is set to relative. And relative for this H1 is mandatory for the span child with position absolute to be well positioned in the page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are trying to do here, but if you are trying to center the text, then here is what I would do:

```
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Hello world</title>
    
        <style>
            /*Puts your header in the center*/
            .positioned {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!--Removed your span because it's unnecessary in this code-->
        <h1 class="positioned">Hello World</h1>
        <div> content after positioned h1. </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

If you want to have the text directly after the headline then I would do this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello world</title>

    <style>
        /*Space the content evenly, so there is space between h1 and your normal div*/
        .container{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <!--Made a div called container and removed your span-->
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <div> content after positioned h1. </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

We don't usually have a lot of tags inside the h1 tag, unless it's a link and your span is pretty much useless here.

PS: Please be more clear about what you want to do with your code.

Comment: I want to center the text, but not in the middle, at 50% but at 25% from the left. I wonder if it can be done with flex.